# Trouble unit-testing "Imperative shell, functional core" in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am creating a class that inherits from `NamedTuple` (for immutability, specifically) that contains three pieces of data in the tuple. I am overriding the `__repr__()` to provide a pretty, human-recognizable representation of the class. However, the custom `__repr__` has to do a few expensive calculations with the data in the tuple in order to provide the pretty representation. As such, my `__repr__` function is organized in the following manner:

```
class MyClass(NamedTuple):
   data1: float
   data2: MyOtherClass
   data3: float


def __repr__():
    exp_1 = self.expensive_function1(self.data1, self.data2, self.data3)
    exp_2 = self.expensive_function2(self.data1, self.data2, self.data3)

    repr_component_1 = MyClass.static_func1(self.data1, exp_1, exp_2)
    repr_component_2 = MyClass.static_func2(self.data2, exp_1, exp_2)
    repr_component_3 = MyClass.static_func2(self.data3, exp_1, exp_2)

    return f"{repr_component_1} {repr_component_2}{repr_component_3}"
```

There is no problem with the code itself. It runs great and works fine. The problem I am having is how to effectively **unit test** the static methods `repr_component_1`, `repr_component_2`, and `repr_component_3`.

If `MyClass` did not specifically need to be immutable, I could throw `exp_1` and `exp_2` into private class attributes and have no problems. However, `MyClass` must be immutable for various reasons.

The trouble is that `exp_1` and `exp_2` are **instance specific** results that are then going into **static methods** as inputs.

As such, the only way I can think of testing this (with `pytest`) is as follows:

```
def test_repr_component_1():
    a = MyClass(data1, data2, data3)
    exp_1 = a.expensive_function1(self.data1, self.data2, self.data3)
    exp_2 = b.expensive_function2(self.data1, self.data2, self.data3)
    result1 = MyClass.static_func1(a.data1, exp_1, exp_2)
    assert result1 == "expected result"
```

However, that's many lines per test scenario (my actual code has more than five lines)! Of course, I wish to test many scenarios. I have heard of set-up and tear-down stuff before but I don't know if that stuff applies in this situation.

Would like to get some thoughts on a "professional" and pythonic way of writing these unit tests.

**EDIT:** It did occur to me to use a Python 3.7 `dataclass` (because of its ability to be 'frozen') which would allow me to set `exp_1` and `exp_2` as private attributes during the `__post_init__` step but I plan on making this a public library and didn't want to have to rely on users having only Python >= 3.7 to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrization will help you to reduce amount of lines of code when writing many scenarios:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data_argument', 'static_func', 'expected_result'],
    [
        [ # scenario 1
            data1,
            data2,
            data3,
            data1, 
            MyClass.static_func1,
            'repr_component1'
        ],
        [ # scenario 2
            data1,
            data2,
            data3,
            data2, 
            MyClass.static_func2,
            'repr_component2'
        ]
    ]
)
def test_repr_component(data1, data2, data3, data_argument, static_func, expected_result):
    a = MyClass(data1, data2, data3) # two scenarios use the same code for tests
    exp_1 = a.expensive_function1(data1, data2, data3)
    exp_2 = a.expensive_function2(data1, data2, data3)
    result = static_func1(data_argument, exp_1, exp_2)
    assert result == expected_result
```